When are solutions to a set of multi-variate quadratic equations isolated points?
Suppose I have set of $n$ multi-variate polynomial equations with $n$ unknowns $x_1, \dots, x_n$. The $n$ equations have real coefficients and are quadratic (so largest degree is $2$). How do I determine when the set of solutions are isolated points as opposed to having uncountably infinite number of solutions?
I think this involves checking conditions about whether the equations share an irreducible component and some mention of Bezout's theorem, but the details are unclear to me. How do I show this rigorously?
As a specific example, suppose that equation $i$ is:
$$ \sum_{j = 1}^n a_{ij} x_i x_j + \sum_{j = 1}^n b_{ij} x_j + 1 = 0$$.
What conditions are necessary on $a_{ij}$ and $b_{ij}$ so the solutions are isolated points?

Deciding if a system of quadratic polynomials has real solution
is NP-hard via reduction from Maximum Independent Set
in a graph,
so you can't expect efficient solution in general unless P=NP.
The reduction.

For each vertex $i$ in the graph add the variable $x_i$.
For each variable $x_i$, add the equation $x_i(x_i-1)=0$
This forces each variable to be zero or one.
For each edge $(u,v)$ in the edges of the graph, add the
equaion $x_u x_v=0$. The forces at least one of the variables to be zero.
Finally, add the equation $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=S$ where
$S$ is the size of the independent set.

